# How to properly close java.net ServerSocket in case of console application termination?

Tags: java, sockets

When running and terminating my java program several times using eclipse an exception occurs:

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

I am aware that it happens because the socket I opened during the previous execution was not closed.

I tried: 
(1) Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook to close the SocketServer instance

(2) close the ServerSocket instance in finally block

```
    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    // propagating Exception(s) to main method for brevity
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(55555, 100,
    InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    System.out.println("Server started  at:  " + serverSocket);

    while (true) {

      System.out.println("Waiting for a  connection...");
      final Socket activeSocket = serverSocket.accept();

      System.out.println("Received a  connection from  " + activeSocket);
      Runnable runnable = () ->  {
         try {
          BufferedReader socketReader = null;
          BufferedWriter socketWriter = null;
          socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activeSocket.getInputStream()));
          socketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(activeSocket.getOutputStream()));
          String incomingMsg = null;
          while ((incomingMsg = socketReader.readLine()) != null) {
              socketWriter.write("Response for message: "+incomingMsg+"\r\n"); // Just a dummy code for brevity
              socketWriter.flush();
          }
         } catch(Exception ex) {
             // I do nothing here for brevity
         }

      };

      new Thread(runnable).start();

    }
   }
   }
```

Can anyone please help me understand how I should solve this and how to properly close the ServerSocket in case of abnormal termination?

Comment: Put a finally block and inside finally block close the socket.